# Are expectation values for any hermitian operator, well defined in case of scattering states, or rather non-normalizable states?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, wavefunction, scattering, hydrogen

Consider I have the following commutator, $[H,O]$ where $O$ is some hermitian operator.

I know that if $$H|\psi\rangle=E|\psi\rangle$$

Where $|\psi\rangle$ represents the bound energy eigenkets, for example the bound states for the Hydrogen atom.
In this case, I know:

$$\langle\psi|[H,O]|\psi\rangle=0$$

However, consider now that I have scattering states, again considering the continuous energy eigenstates of the hydrogen atom. Does the above equation still hold true in this case ?

Are expectation values for any hermitian operator, well defined in case of scattering states, or rather non-normalizable states ?

Comment: Yes. [Linked](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/44839/scattering-states-of-hydrogen-atom-in-non-relativistic-perturbation-theory).